AFCS LTspice noise injection on the input lines
I have an input filter and I am simulating the AFCS on the input lines.  What do i need to look for when I am injecting noise into the input lines ?
My understanding is that to see if the filter damps out the noise and the output does not see the noise.

Can you show an example schematic.

What does AFCS stand for?

@qrk Google tells me that it is the Air Force Civilian Service. But of course that can't be right. ;) So it might be an Aircraft Flight Control System...?
